# Displaying tilemap in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Here is the code I'm using right now to try to generate a tilemap:

```
// --- Javascript ---

window.onload = function (){
  var can = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  var map = {
  cols: 8, //# of cols
  rows: 8, // # of rows
  tSize: 32, // tile size (32px x 32px)
  tiles: [
    [1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
  ], // map
};

var tileAtlas = new Image();
tileAtlas.src = 'Tiles.png';
tileAtlas.onload = function () {
  for (var c = 0; c < map.cols; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < map.rows; r++) {
      if (map.tiles[c][r] !== 0) { // 0 is an empty tile
        ctx.drawImage(
          tileAtlas, // image
          map.tiles[c][r] * 32, // cut start x
          0, // cut start y
          map.tsize, // size of tiles for cut size x
          map.tsize, // size of tiles for cut size y
          c * map.tsize, // place tiles on canvas x
          r * map.tsize, // place tiles on canvas y
          map.tsize, // place height
          map.tsize // place width
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

here is the [spritesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JX3d.png)

It was supposed to show an 8x8 grid of "grass" but it was blank yet the console was clear

Comment: For the line `if (1 !== 0) { // 0 is an empty tile`, is that the *actual* code you're using right now, or was there a typo when you copied the code over?

Comment: `tsize` and `tSize` are not the same thing.

Comment: sorry, no that was to try debugging because the whole thing was not a blank space so I just made it always true. it's `if(tiles[c][r] !== 0){ // 0 is an empty tile`

Comment: Please edit your code in the question to include that correction @Gamecocks20048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `tsize` (versus `tSize`). Also, the expression for the second argument seems not what you want. You can just pass a 0:

```
ctx.drawImage(
    tileAtlas, // image
    0,
    0,
    map.tSize, // size of tiles for cut size x
    map.tSize, // size of tiles for cut size y
    c * map.tSize, // place tiles on canvas x
    r * map.tSize, // place tiles on canvas y
    map.tSize, // place height
    map.tSize // place width
);
```

```js
var can = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
var map = {
    cols: 8, //# of cols
    rows: 8, // # of rows
    tSize: 32, // tile size (32px x 32px)
    tiles: [
        [1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    ], // map
};

var tileAtlas = new Image();
tileAtlas.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JX3d.png';
tileAtlas.onload = function () {
    for (var c = 0; c < map.cols; c++) {
        for (var r = 0; r < map.rows; r++) {
            ctx.drawImage(
                tileAtlas, // image
                0, 
                0,
                map.tSize, // size of tiles for cut size x
                map.tSize, // size of tiles for cut size y
                c * map.tSize, // place tiles on canvas x
                r * map.tSize, // place tiles on canvas y
                map.tSize, // place height
                map.tSize // place width
            );

        }
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="256px" height="256px"></canvas>
```

Comment: That is very close to what I was looking for but I want just the 1st element no the whole picture so the grass before the dirt sprite

Comment: So then pass as the second and third argument a zero. Updated answer accordingly.